# HashMap Value which is an object has an attribute overridden with incorrect value

Tags: java, hashmap

I am iterating over a hashmap that has objects as values and strings as keys.

```
 ResultSet myresults = st.executeQuery("SELECT traces.* from traces");

    while (myresults.next()) {
        MethodTrace MethodTrace = new MethodTrace();
        Method method= new Method(); 
        Requirement requirement= new Requirement(); 



 requirement=RequirementHashMap.get(myresults.getString("requirementid")); 
         method = MethodHashMap.get(myresults.getString("methodid")); 

        MethodTrace.setMethod(method);
        MethodTrace.setRequirement(requirement);

        //checking whether the method is present in the superclasses


        MethodTrace.setGold(myresults.getString("goldfinal"));
        String reqMethod=MethodTrace.Requirement.ID+"-"+MethodTrace.Method.ID; 
        String reqClass=MethodTrace.Requirement.ID+"-"+MethodTrace.Method.Owner.ID;  

    //THIS IS THE LINE RESPONSIBLE FOR THE BUG  
MethodTrace.Method.Owner.DeveloperGold=classTraceHashMap.get(reqClass).DeveloperGold; 



         System.out.println(reqMethod+"-");

         methodtraceHashMap.put(reqMethod, MethodTrace);
     //         System.out.println("WE ARE IN THE LOOP "+methodtraceHashMap.get("1-1"));
    //          System.out.println("WE ARE IN THE LOOP "+methodtraceHashMap.get("1-1"));



    }
```

Here is a simplified version of my code highlighting the nature of my bug and the exact location of it:

```
 for(MethodTrace MethodTrace: methodtraceHashMap2.values()) {
        String reqClass=MethodTrace.Requirement.ID+"-"+MethodTrace.Method.Owner.ID;  
        String reqMethod=MethodTrace.Requirement.ID+"-"+MethodTrace.Method.ID; 
//THIS IS THE LINE RESPONSIBLE FOR THE BUG           MethodTrace.Method.Owner.DeveloperGold=classTraceHashMap.get(reqClass).DeveloperGold; 

        methodtraceHashMap2.put(reqMethod, MethodTrace);
        System.out.println(methodtraceHashMap2.get("1-1").Method.Owner.getDeveloperGold());
    }
```

I am setting the value of each object in the hashmap by retrieving its value from another hashmap as shown in the following line

```
MethodTrace.Method.Owner.DeveloperGold=classTraceHashMap.get(reqClass).DeveloperGold;
```

I am setting the value of `methodtraceHashMap2.get("1-1").Method.Owner.getDeveloperGold()` to `"T"` in the first iteration of my loop, when I move to the second iteration of my loop, my loop sets the value for another key (key "2-1"): `methodtraceHashMap2.get("2-1").Method.Owner.getDeveloperGold()` to `"N"`, the problem is that `methodtraceHashMap2.get("1-1").Method.Owner.getDeveloperGold()` ends up being set to `"N"` as well in the second iteration of my loop while it should be `"T"` as it was set to `"T"` in the first iteration.

Here are my other classes

```
public final class MethodTrace {
    public static boolean modified = false;
    public Method Method= new Method();
    public Requirement Requirement=new Requirement();
    public String gold;
    public String prediction; 
    public String goldfinal;
    public String likelihood;
    public String why;
    boolean SubjectDeveloperEqualityFlag;
    public Methods<String> SuperClassesListMethodTraces;
    public Methods<String> InterfaceListMethodTraces;
    public Methods<String> ChildrenListMethodTraces;
    public Methods<String> ImplementationListMethodTraces;

    public boolean TraceSet; 
}

public class Method {
    public String ID; 
    public String methodname;
    public String fullmethodname;
    public Clazz Owner= new Clazz(); 
    public MethodList Callees= new MethodList(); 
    public MethodList Callers= new MethodList(); 
    public MethodList Interfaces= new MethodList(); 
    public MethodList Implementations= new MethodList(); 
    public MethodList Superclasses= new MethodList(); 
    public MethodList Children= new MethodList(); 
}

public class Clazz {

    public String ID; 
    public String classname;
    public String DeveloperGold=new String(); 
    public String SubjectGold; 
    public List<Clazz> Children= new ArrayList<Clazz>(); 
    public List<Clazz> Parents= new ArrayList<Clazz>();  
    public List<Clazz> Interfaces= new ArrayList<Clazz>();  
    public List<Clazz> Implementations= new ArrayList<Clazz>(); 
    public MethodList methods = new MethodList(); 
}
```

Here is the declaration of MethodTraceHashMap2:

```
static LinkedHashMap<String, MethodTrace> methodtraceHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, MethodTrace>();
```

Comment: This would be less confusing if you used names starting with lower-case characters for variables. I assume `Method`, `Owner` and `DeveloperGold` are public fields, is that correct? Perhaps any of them is accidentally declared `static`?

Comment: I agree with @Hulk. I assume Requirement and ID are not defined as static. Maybe post these classes as well. The methodtraceHashMap2.put() is not necessary. You are not putting another MethodTrace instance in the map, you just modify an attribute or it.

Comment: just added them

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to alter a collection while iterating it.

Answer (score 0):

From the behaviour you have mentioned, It seems like the object in the hashmap is same for all the keys i.e.

```
Object firstObject = new Object();
for(.......){
firstObject.setDevloperGold("value");
methodtraceHashMap2.put("key",firstObject);
}
```

That's why when you make change in first Iteration it reflects in past Iterations.Instead you should have done

```
for(.......){
Object firstObject = new Object();
firstObject.setDevloperGold("value");
methodtraceHashMap2.put("key",firstObject);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I already create my object inside the loop not outside so your suggestion would not work

Comment: can you share where you are adding values to `methodtraceHashMap2` Map?

Comment: just added my original code in thwe top of the post

Answer (score 0):

Your loop has the following logic

- For each MethodTrace in the values of methodtraceHashMap2

  - Derive a key from Requirement.ID and Owner.ID
  - Get a value from classTraceHashMap using that key and replace the DeveloperGold field in MethodTrace with the value
  - Derive another key from Requirement.ID and Method.ID
  - Put the MethodTrace object in the methodtraceHashMap2 map with the second key

If what you are trying to do is lookup the DeveloperGold value and put it in each MethodTrace, then you don't need the last 2 steps. i.e. just the following will do what you want.

- For each MethodTrace in the values of methodtraceHashMap2

  - Derive a key from Requirement.ID and Owner.ID
  - Get a value from classTraceHashMap using that key and replace the DeveloperGold field in MethodTrace with the value

If on the other hand you are changing the key for the MethodTrace in the map, while you are looping around the values of that map, then that's a bad idea. You should save them all to a new map.